# WAMP-Mysql service not starting

Tags: mysql, wamp

MySQL service isn't starting with WAMP and this is the error log which I get:

```
130309 22:37:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130309 22:37:18 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
130309 22:37:18 [ERROR] wampmysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
130309 22:37:18 [ERROR] Aborting <enter code here>
```

Comment: I've had similar problems, sometimes I need to stop all services, then start up one at a time (apache, mysql, then php)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the my.ini ( using the wampmanager -> MYSQL -> My.ini menu link )

Change the parameter skip-locking to skip-external-locking

Comment: Then you edited the wrong file, or you have another my.ini file. This can happen, so search for 'my.ini' and 'my.cnf' and if you find any `not in the /wamp/...` folder structure. Delete them.

Comment: Answer from RiggsFolly is solved my problem. Open Explore, go to "C:"
Than find "my.ini" and delete if not in the "C:\wamp"